# Unable to get response from CORS enabled API using the Angular 5 application

Tags: angular, cors, watson-conversation, angular-httpclient

I want to call Watson conversation API from the Angular 5 application and for that, I'm using Angular HttpClient.

Below is the code snippet:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
const url = 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api?version=2017-05-26';
const username = 'my-username';
const password = 'secret';
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
  Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(`${username}:${password}`)
});
this.httpClient.get('https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api?version=2017-05-26', { headers: headers })
  .subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
  });
```

It should call the API and return the response but it returns an error as below:

```
Failed to load https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api?version=2017-05-26: Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

The request works perfectly with Postman and Node.js request package but not working with the Angular 5 app.

Sample cURL request:

```
curl -u "{username}":"{password}" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api/v1/{method}"
```

Above request works fine if I add [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) extension in the chrome, so unable to understand what's the problem with the Angular app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: CORS is enforced by the browser, therefore not applicable to curl. Angular is not involved in any way here. You need to configure the server to respond with the expected headers, then the browser will make the requests.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Do you mean I can't directly call this API from the Angular?

Comment: Angular is not related to this topic. It's an issue between the browser and the server. The browser will refuse to make the actual request when a preflight request doesn't respond with the expected headers. If you don't control the server and can't change its configuration, you can work around by making the request from a server that you control. As mentioned CORS only applies to the browser, therefore server-side code can make requests to such a server. You can then provide an API for the browser to use.

Comment: But when I added Allow-Control-Allow-Origin extension to chrome, it worked, how did it work then?

Comment: Because extensions can do things JS in web pages can't.

Comment: When the browser does the OPTIONS request, I'm getting the expected headers in the response but still, it is not making the actual GET request.
I'm getting 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' and 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' headers.

Comment: The error message tells you which headers are missing.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the time. All you need to do is, to ensure the server response contains the headers the browser complains about.

Comment: Alright, I got your point. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I've figured out the problem, it is from the server side, Access-Control-Allow-Headers are not properly set from the server side**.

I was trying to set 'Authorization' header but it wasn't listed in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' and that's why browser was giving the error.

In the preflight request, the browser will only allow you to add those headers from the client-side(which is Angular in my case) that are listed in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'.